# Suppose $A$ is a 4x4 matrix such that $\det(A)=\frac{1}{64}$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Suppose A is a 4x4 matrix such that $\det(A)=\frac{1}{64}$ then $\det(4A^{-1})^T$

1. I created a 2x2 matrix $B$ and transposed it both had the same determinant
2. I then found $\det(B)$ and $\det(B^{-1})$ the results were inverses of each other
3. I then tried found the $\det(2B)$

but I cannot see what is the relationship between the determinant of a matrix and the determinant of that matrix multiplied by a constant?

Comment: You want to use that the determinant of $C^{T}$ is the same as the determinant of $C$, the determinant of $C^{-1}$ is the inverse of the determinant of $C$, and the determinant of $kC$ is $k^n$ multiplied by the determinant of $C$, if C is an $n\times n$ matrix.

Comment: Same question as me   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910647/determinants-of-matrices-det4a-equals/910660?noredirect=1#comment1879111_910660

Unisa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Scaling a single row (or column) by a constant $k$ results in the determinant being scaled by $k$. So what happens if the entire matrix is scaled by $k$?

Comment: Then the determinant should scale by the number of rows and columns that was affected being a 4X4 matrix it should scale 16 thank you

Comment: @Gobabis: are you sure it scales by $16$?

Comment: it seems to make sence at the matrix is 4x4 that is 16 and then by 4

Comment: Yes, it gets scaled by $2^4 = 16$.

Answer (score 3):

Use those properties:

For $A\in\mathcal M_n(\Bbb C)$ we have

- $\det(kA)=k^n\det(A)$
- If $A$ is invertible then $\det(A^{-1})=\frac{1}{\det (A)}$
- $\det(A^T)=\det(A)$

Answer (score 2):

As a real-valued function on $n \times n$ matrices, the determinant is a polynomial of degree $n$ in the entries of a matrix, and the polynomial is homogeneous (all of its terms have the same degree), so $\det(\lambda A) = \lambda^n \det A$.

For example, for $n = 2$,

$\det\left(\begin{array}{cc}a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right) = ad - bc$,

and

$\det \left[ \lambda \left(\begin{array}{cc}a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right) \right] = \det\left(\begin{array}{cc}\lambda a & \lambda b \\ \lambda c & \lambda d \end{array} \right) = (\lambda a)(\lambda d) - (\lambda b)(\lambda c) = \lambda^2 (ad - bc)$.