# Determinants of Matrices det(4A) equals?

Tags: matrices, determinant, inverse, matrix-equations

Suppose A is a 4 x 4 matrix such that $\det(A) = 1/64$. What will $\det(4A^{-1})^T$ be equal to?

Here's my thinking,
$\det(A^T) = \det(A)$
I has no effect on the determinant.
And $\det(A^{-1}) = 1/\det(A)$
so $\det(4A^{-1}) = \det(4\times64)$ = can't be 256?

I don't understand, Please help me!
THANKS!

Comment: I Think I may have figured it out! ok my thinking is, it is a 4x4 matrix so det(4A) will equal 4^4det(A) = 256det(A)

Comment: It seems we are doing the same course

Comment: MAT1503 Linear Algebra :) What are you studying?

Comment: Same :) MAT1503

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is a square $n$ matrix, $\mathrm{det}(x.A)=x^n.\mathrm{det}(A)$.

So here, $\mathrm{det}(4A^{-1})=4^4 . \mathrm{det}(A^{-1})=256. \mathrm{det}(A)^{-1}=256*64$

Comment: AAAH yes thank you! I just saw this in a textbook on line if it were a 5x5 matrix it would be 4^5.det(A)

Comment: Ok wait so I thought the answer would then be 256 x 64 = 16384

Comment: The answer is 16384?

Comment: Sorry, I have red that $det(A)$ was $64$ ^^